# PHP GAE app strange error accounts.google.com

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

i am creating GAE app with php, its a simple form which gets user information and store it in GAE datastore and cloud storage. for some reason its not working and giving below error, it was working earlier.

LOG

```
The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'Couldn't 
resolve host 'accounts.google.com'' in
/base/data/home/apps/s~appname1/1.380341202009680948/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Curl.php:81
    Stack trace:
    0 /base/data/home/apps/s~appname1/1.380341202009680948/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php(122): Google_IO_Curl->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
    1 /base/data/home/apps/s~appname1/1.380341202009680948/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(320): Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the addition of cURL in the latest runtime. You need to update the google api client from [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Comment: ah thats painful... let me check it, thanks for your help and its good to know that they have added curl lib with app engine. will play with that.

Comment: we're going to revert the change - you will have some time to upgrade to a new version of the API client library.

Comment: didnt get you, which part will be reverted curl, or something else and when you will change it again? how can i get alert for that.